# Xcode Playground doesn't show result sidebar

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

A version of my Xcode is 12.5.1. I clicked "File"-"New"-"Playground" and "iOS"-"Blank"-"next" and "create". Then I can see the following code:

```
import UIKit

var greeting = "Hello, playground"
```

But I cannot see anything on the right side bar which is supposed to show the result, "Hello, playground".
I clicked the play button and also "Editor"-"Run Playground" but it's still the same.
What should I do to see the result?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `print(greeting)`?
Also, I've heard to just restart Xcode when this happens and it will work.